# Marking an item in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using a listView on virtual mode, and on SearchForVirtualItem event I would like to mark the found item, the same way that clicking on this item would highlight it (a blue back color).

I have tried: `listView.Items[foundItem.Index].Selected = true;`

but it does not highlight it the same way (a light gray back color).
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call .Select

```
listView.Items[foundItem.Index].Selected = true;
listView.Select();
```

Comment: And this would means, what [`HideSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) is set to `True` (default value). Other solution would be to set it to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

While you're setting the selection (which gives the blue colour), I believe the grey outline comes from the focus. You can get around this by adding this line below your current one:

```
listView.Items[foundItem.Index].Focused = true;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You need to call .Select see my post.

Comment: I thought that .Select() selected the control (in this case the ListView), but wouldn't affect the selection of the items in the control. I could be wrong, though.